# Automation tool to convert PSD to HTML

Tags: html, image-scaling, slice, psd

Problem - Is there any online tool or automated built in tool to convert a PSD file into HTML code or HTML web page ???

Comment: you should try and update your question so it is less vague and solicit better responses before it is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can... it is built right into photoshop and part of "save for web" options...

[image]

**HOWEVER** though this exists, it is VERY limited in what it can do and should really be used as a springboard from which to jump of from. You can set it up to export the document as a CSS div layout, or a table layout (for an email as an example).

I woudl do some research on the "Save For Web" parameters and see if it sets you up in the right direction. It is in no way a substitute for understanding good coding practices, but for a quick functional example online for a mock-up, it will suffice.